# 'set fileencoding' for new files. Vim says it won't work, but is it really so?

Tags: vimrc, encoding

```
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencoding=cp1251
set fileencodings=ut8-8,latin1
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%{(&fileencoding)}
```

Vim help says that only global value of `fileencoding` won't for new empty buffers.

> Note that 'fileencodings' is not used for a new file, the global value
> of 'fileencoding' is used instead.  You can set it with:
> :setglobal fenc=iso-8859-2

But as far as I can see, it works.

Open Vim, open some file (just in case), and then open a new empty buffer (with `:enew`, `:new`, or `:vnew`). Notice the encoding in status line is cp1251.

Why?

Comment: Uh, the documentation says "fileencodingS" (plural) doesn't work for new files, so if your new file was `utf8-8` or `latin1` which is what you have in `'fileencodings'` then that would be incorrect. Looks like it's working just as described in the docs, no?

Comment: Well, yes. But it is written that "... **global** value of 'fileencoding' is used". I haven't specified `fileencoding` by using `setglobal`. It is specified with regular `set`...

Comment: See [`:help local-options`](https://vimhelp.org/options.txt.html#local-options): "With `:set` both the local and global value is changed. With `:setlocal` only the local value is changed, thus this value is not used when editing a new buffer."

Comment: If you feel lost then do `:verbose setglobal fenc?` and see that it was really set by your vimrc.